# Prisoner Voting Incentives

Tags: game-theory

**Exposition**

Suppose that there are 100 prisoners (arbitrary amount) who have to follow a strict set of rules.

One of these rules is that they must be in bed by 10pm every single night. However, the majority of prisoners want this changed.

The prison guards allow the prisoners to vote to change their bed time, but require a super majority to agree that the bed time should be changed: if >=75% of votes agree that yes, the bed time should be changed, then the prison guards will change it.

**The Dilemma**

The prisoners are given the following option: they may give up a fixed amount of food ration in order to gain an extra vote. In fact, they may obtain an extra vote for every food ration that is relinquished.

Assume that the prisoners have a vested enough interest in the vote to give up their food rations. Also assume that there is no demographic correlation between one's overall willingness to give up food and their vote.

If you assume that a yes voter and no voter are just as likely to purchase extra votes, these votes should essentially cancel out.

**The Question**

Can you expect that no voters have a higher incentive to purchase extra votes, given that the threshold of voting is 75%?

If the amount of votes bought per capita is the same on either side, the votes cancel, but should you naturally expect there to be higher votes bought per capita for no voters?

A no vote carries more power than a yes vote, so I can see this being the case, but I am not sure.

Comment: Only if the percentage of prisoners who want the change is exactly $75\%$

Comment: You haven't defined the percentage of 'majority of prisoners want this changed' making this a question that is extremely open-ended

Comment: @yolo Nobody knows the percentage of prisoners who want the change, that is the point of the vote. The prisoners wouldn't know this information, so it should not affect their decision making, and is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This depends on how many times each side out thinks each other:**

1st move: YES voters are confident and don't spend rations.

2nd move: If NO voters out-think them they spend more rations to vote NO

3rd move: If YES voters figure NO voters would try to spend more rations to change the vote 
they do the same

4th move: If NO voters think this far ahead they quit altogether as there is no point in wasting rations

5th move: Like move one YES voters don't bother spending rations because they foresee move 4

i.e moves 1-4 iterate and in only move 2. That gives quantifies 'incentive' as a quarter which is not very appealing

**Alternatively:**

If we say that infinite rations are allowed instead of move 4 you'd reach:

4th move: NO voters further sacrifice rations to boost their NO votes

5th move: YES voters further sacrifice rations to boost their YES votes

This pattern re-iterated instead causing half the total moves to be in favor of NO voters and half to be in favor of YES voters causing the incentive to be a half which means no equal incentive.

**However:**

The fact that if there was no extra votes the general result would be half likely (75-100 people vote yes) doesn't make a difference. due to how the chances are fair. So technically, this is experimentally an even vote. The fact that 75% is the required majority for YES people and over 50% of people are YES people cancel out

We can demonstrate this in this way:

Now that we have our 'quantified incentivity' we can now approach what would happen in a change of threshold. Our current incentivity is:

0.75 for Yes or 0.5 for Yes

0.25 for No  or 0.5 for No

Since we have seen that the 75% threshold splits the boundary of YES voters in half the incentives are multiplied as such:

0.0375 for Yes or 0.25 for Yes

0.0125 for No  or 0.25 for No

...essentially the ratio between the two stays the same. However if we bring the threshold up (such as 99%) the probability for YES to lose generally is greater which multiplies to the YES incentive to get more votes.  The probability for NO to lose goes down so that is multiplied to the NO incentive. Hence:

0.75 `X` ((100-99)/(100-50))for Yes    or 0.25 `X` ((100-99)/(100-50))for Yes

0.0125 `X` (1-((100-99)/(100-50))) for No  or 0.25 `X` (1-((100-99)/(100-50))) for No

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm satisfied with this yet.

Consider if the threshold were 99% rather than 75%. If you're a no voter, you have a lot of confidence that if you purchase an extra vote, it can make a significant difference on whether or not the vote passes.

If you're a yes voter, buying a single vote doesn't affect the poll that much.

Are you saying that there is something that could cancel out this difference in incentives, like the fact that a 99% threshold is unlikely to be passed anyway?

Thank you for taking the time to think about this, by the way

Comment: Allow me to ammend the question to suffice this

Comment: Okay, I think you're completely right that their incentives would stay equal because a higher voting threshold means that it's less likely to pass. Thank you for answering this.

What if we assume a 99% threshold, but assume that 99 out of the 100 people are voting yes and 1 out of the 100 is voting no. Should we expect the no voter to purchase more votes than the average yes voter, and for the vote to fail?

Comment: That was the second example i gave. The incentive results are at the bottom